# Why does my code create a new empty array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my code:

```
const Practice = () => {
    const [todo, setTodo] =useState("");
    const [todos,setTodos]=useState([])
    const onSubmit =async(event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        setTodos((currnet)=>[todo, ...currnet])
        setTodo("")
        try {
            const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "todos"), {
              todos,
            });
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
          } catch (e) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
          }
    }
    const onChange = (event)=>{
        setTodo(event.target.value)
    }
    console.log(todos)
  return (
    <>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <input onChange={onChange} value={todo} type="text" placeholder="Write" />
            <input type="submit" value="GO!!" />
        </form>
    </>
  )
}
```

and I input some words in tag but last input word dosen't exist my firebase database. why dosen't exist my database? and why create new empty array?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMZ2u.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNEfi.png)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is related to the asynchronous nature of the hooks.

In `onSubmit` function, you are setting `todos` using `setTodos` hook (that is async) and then you are reading `todos` value (to store it into firebase).

You can't write this code in an async context! Infact, could be that `todos` will be read before hook setted him (and the result will be that not all the data will be stored into firebase).

To solve this bug you have to use `useEffect` hook in this way:

```
const Practice = () => {
    const [todo, setTodo] =useState("");
    const [todos,setTodos]=useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        // 1) define an async function in useEffect hook
        const storeData = async () => {
           try {
            const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "todos"), {
              todos,
            });
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
          } catch (e) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
          }
        }

        // 2) reset todo
        setTodo("");
        // 3) store todos into firebase
        storeData();

    }, [todos]);

    const onSubmit =async(event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        setTodos((currnet)=>[todo, ...currnet]);
    }
    const onChange = (event)=>{
        setTodo(event.target.value)
    }
  return (
    <>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <input onChange={onChange} value={todo} type="text" placeholder="Write" />
            <input type="submit" value="GO!!" />
        </form>
    </>
  )
}
```

Explanation:

1. `onSubmit` function needs just to set `todos` (no further action required);
2. When `todos` changes, `useEffect` hook will be called (only at this time you are 100% sure that `todos` will contain all the elements you have to store into firebase!);
3. Now in `useEffect` you can clean `todo` and then call `storeData` function to store `todos` into firebase.

Additional note: why I defined an async function in `useEffect` if I could write something like:

```
useEffect(async () => {    // never use async useEffect!!!
  try {
     const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "todos"), {
        todos,
     });
     console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
  } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
  }
}, [todos])
```

There is a reason why you can't write async `useEffect` but I'm not an expert so I strongly suggest you to read [this](https://devtrium.com/posts/async-functions-useeffect) article.